# div / border not scaling with img

Tags: html, css

I have an image with an offset border. It works perfectly on mobile, but once scaled up, the div stays the same height, and so the border does not stay with the image. Tried to add a min() to the size but that didn't change anything. I'm being dumb? Thanks guys! See image below for an example of what I want.

HTML:

```html
<!-- profile picture -->[![enter image description here][1]][1]
<div class="profile">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <img src="{% static 'haloassets/images/PaulBG.jpg' %}" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS/SCSS:

```css
.profile {
  width: 85vw;
  height: 21vh;
  float: right;
  transform: translateX(2rem);
  position: relative;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .border {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid $primary;
    top: 10px;
    left: -10px;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Scaled up as in using browser controls? Have you considered a pseudo-element rather than a separate div?

Comment: yes, my bad, with browser controls. Ahh use pseudo on the img itself?

Comment: btw you are missing a curly bracket

Comment: @DedS3t that's a brace. Let's not confuse the internet with fuzzy terminology. :)

Comment: are you trying to have a overlay sort of effect on image ?

Comment: @isherwood u good bro, its not fuzzy terminology, they are known as both curly brackets and braces.

Comment: @PrinceSingh Yes, I've attached an image now to show what I meant.

Comment: @MatthewCasey checkout my answer if it helps you out

Comment: Why don't you have the image inside the border?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.border, img {
  position : absolute;
  left :0;
  top:0;
}
.border{
  outline: 4px solid red;
  outline-offset: 0px;
  margin: 15px -15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
            
    <div class="border">

    </div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300X200" alt="" />
</div>
```